# "awk" and "cut" behaving differently in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to cut the below string starting on the single quote:

```
name1=O'Reilly
```

so it leaves:

```
name2=Reilly
```

That's easy from the command line with the following commands:

```
echo $name | cut -d\' -f
echo $name | awk -F\' '{print $2}'
```

However when I run these commands from a script the string remains unaltered. I've been looking into problems with using single quotes as a delimiter but couldn't find anything. Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: What is error you see? name, name1 or name2 ?

Comment: $name != $name1

Comment: Sorry, my explanation led to confusions. I don't have any problem with the commands per se, when I run them in the command line I get the desired results, those are the instructions again:

name=O'Reilly
echo  name | cut -d\' -f
echo $name | awk -F\' '{print $2}'

In both cases the output is "Reilly", which is what I need. The problem is, when I run this from a bash script the output is O'Reilly. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That does not change the string the variable expands to, it just outputs the result of string manipulation.

If you want to create a new reference for variable `name`, use command substitution to save the result of `cut`/`awk` operation as variable `name`:

```
% name="O'Reilly"                           

% echo "$name" | awk -F\' '{print $2}'        
Reilly

% name=$(echo "$name" | awk -F\' '{print $2}')

% echo "$name"                              
Reilly
```

On the other hand, if you want to declare the input as one (`name1`), and save the output as a different variable (`name2`):

```
% name1="O'Reilly"                          

% name2=$(echo "$name1" | awk -F\' '{print $2}')

% echo "$name2"                               
Reilly
```

---

This might be easier to get using Parameter expansion though:

```
$ name="O'Reilly"

$ echo "${name#*\'}"
Reilly

$ name="${name#*\'}"

$ echo "$name"
Reilly
```